# Specifying custom model of decision nodes in HydeNet

Tags: r, jags, bayesian-networks

I am building a Bayesian Decision Network using `HydeNet` package:

[image]

The Market node and the Survey node have custom probability and cpt nature respectively. The idea is to define Found node as a Decision node with following logic: the agent is calculating his Utility according to the Survey node info, and then making a decision whether or not found a company on the market. Here I've calculated the ExpUtility values separately and then just paste them into determ node:

```
# Found node (how to put down an optimization task on it?)
founding <- data.frame(Found = as.factor(c(rep(0,3), rep(1,3))),
                       Survey = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3),2)),
                       EV = as.numeric(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)))

expvalue = function(founding_option, survey_option){
  df = outcomes %>%  
    left_join(market_status, by = "Market") %>% 
    inner_join(survey_cond, by = "Market") %>% 
    filter(Found == founding_option) %>% 
    filter(Survey == survey_option) %>% 
    mutate(expexted = as.numeric(as.character(Utility))*prob_real*prob_surv)
  ev = sum(df$expexted)
  return(ev)
}

for (i in 1:nrow(founding)) {
  founding$EV[i] = expvalue(founding$Found[i], founding$Survey[i])
}

net <- setNode(net, Found, nodeType = "determ", define=fromFormula(),
              nodeFormula = Found~ifelse(Survey == "1", 0, 1))
net <- setDecisionNodes(net, Found)
```

How can I code the ExpUtility maximizing process in the node?

upd: the formula of ExpValue is:

[image]

so the agent decides to found a company if the ExpUtility of founding is greater than 0 (which is the utility of no founding on the definition).

Full code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(HydeNet)

# 1 - poor, 2 - medium, 3 - perspective
market_status = data.frame(Market = as.factor(c(1,2,3)),
                           prob_real = as.numeric(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))

# the probability of defining the market status
survey_cond = data.frame(Market = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3),3)),
                         Survey = as.factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3))),
                         prob_surv = as.numeric(c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5)))


# final utilities
outcomes = data.frame(Found = as.factor(c(rep(0,3), rep(1,3))),
                      Market = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3),2)),
                      Utility = as.factor(c(0,0,0,-7,5,20)))


net <- HydeNetwork(~ Utility | Found*Market
                   + Found | Survey
                   + Survey | Market)

plot(net)

# Market node 
net <- setNode(net, Market, nodeType="dcat",  pi=vectorProbs(p=market_status$prob_real, Market), 
               factorLevels = c("1","2","3"))

# Survey node 
survey.cpt <- cpt(Survey ~ Market,
                  data = survey_cond,
                  wt = survey_cond$prob_surv)
net <- setNodeModels(net, survey.cpt)

# Found node (how to put down an optimization task on it?)
founding <- data.frame(Found = as.factor(c(rep(0,3), rep(1,3))),
                       Survey = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3),2)),
                       EV = as.numeric(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)))

expvalue = function(founding_option, survey_option){
  df = outcomes %>%  
    left_join(market_status, by = "Market") %>% 
    inner_join(survey_cond, by = "Market") %>% 
    filter(Found == founding_option) %>% 
    filter(Survey == survey_option) %>% 
    mutate(expexted = as.numeric(as.character(Utility))*prob_real*prob_surv)
  ev = sum(df$expexted)
  return(ev)
}

for (i in 1:nrow(founding)) {
  founding$EV[i] = expvalue(founding$Found[i], founding$Survey[i])
}

net <- setNode(net, Found, nodeType = "determ", define=fromFormula(),
              nodeFormula = Found~ifelse(Survey == "1", 0, 1))
net <- setDecisionNodes(net, Found)

# Utility node
net <- setNode(net, Utility, "determ", define=fromFormula(),
               nodeFormula = Utility ~ ifelse(Found == 0, 0,
                                              ifelse(Market == 1, -7, 
                                                     ifelse(Market == 2, 5, 20))))
net <- setUtilityNodes(net, Utility)

plot(net)

trackedVars <- c("Market","Survey","Found","Utility")
evidence <- NULL
compiledNet <- compileJagsModel(net, data = evidence,
                                n.chains = 3,
                                n.adapt = 5000)
post <- HydeSim(compiledNet,
                variable.names = trackedVars,
                n.iter=10000)

dplyr::sample_n(post, 20)
table(post$Utility)
mean(post$Utility)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know HydeNet but with pyAgrum, you can do that quite easily :

```py
infdiag=gum.fastID("Market{poor|medium|perspective}->Survey{poor|medium|perspective}->*Found{nOK|OK}->$Utility[3]<-Market")
infdiag.cpt("Market")[:]=[0.5,0.3,0.2]
infdiag.cpt("Survey")[{"Market":"poor"}]=[0.6,0.3,0.1]
infdiag.cpt("Survey")[{"Market":"medium"}]=[0.3,0.4,0.3]
infdiag.cpt("Survey")[{"Market":"perspective"}]=[0.1,0.3,0.6]
infdiag.utility("Utility").fillWith([0,0,0,-7,5,20])

ie=gum.ShaferShenoyLIMIDInference(infdiag)
ie.makeInference()
print(ie.optimalDecision("Found"))
```

for this result :

```
      ||  Found            |
Survey||nOK      |OK       |
------||---------|---------|
poor  || 1.0000  | 0.0000  |
medium|| 0.0000  | 1.0000  |
perspe|| 0.0000  | 1.0000  |
```

In a notebook :
[image: influence diagram with pyAgrum]

PS- I changed some values in P(survey|Market) in ordre to have a correct CPT. I can assume that the values in the utility are not the right ones either...

Comment: I didn't really understand why values in P(Survey|Market) are wrong: this parameter show us the probability of certain survey value (s1, s2, s3) under each market state. Sum of each market state is 1, so it is correct, isn't it?
Additionally, thanks for your solution, but because of big number of packages and analysis I'd prefer to stay with R.

Comment: No problem of course, I just wanted to show a solution that seemed simpler (to me).

About your parameters, you're right .. my bad : I directly took this list 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5 as a CPT ... but for pyAgrum, it should have been transposed  :
0.6,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.5 (which makes it easier to check the sum ;-) ).